# MoveToRegion in xamarin forms maps behaves strangely

Tags: ios, mkmapview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I am using a Map control in my app, and i need to set the visible region in such a way that it should cover all the pins.
Irony is same code doesn't work on both the platform, iOS works awkwardly , below code yield almost the same visible region in both platform.

```
 if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                customMap.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (customMap.CustomPins [0].Pin.Position, Distance.FromMiles (0.20)));
if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                customMap.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (customMap.CustomPins [0].Pin.Position, Distance.FromMiles (55.0)));
```

Can anyone explains it? why I need to code like it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have found a workaround , i am waiting for some explanation before accepting my own answer for it

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), () =>
                    {
                        customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(customMap.CustomPins [0].Pin.Position, Distance.FromMiles(55.0)));
                        return false;
                    });
```

Comment: No idea why this works on ios but it does. Perhaps it needs to happen over a time period?

Comment: yeah i realised  that it needs to be  delayed a bit

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a problem where the MovetoRegion was being delayed (15-30 seconds) when trying to center on the users current location using the Xamarin Geolocator Plugin, on both IOS and Android.  Things work alot better with Saket Kumar's approach with the 500ms delay.  Here is my code snippet, hope this helps someone.

```
    private void CenterOnMe_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        var t = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), () =>
            {
                AroundMeMap.MoveToRegion(

                    MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(

                        new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1)));
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
```